# Can an Omni Channel agent login and accept cases from the mobile app?

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

I have a requirement for a skills-based routing App to exist entirely in a Mobile Experience. Since the Utility Bar works in Desktop only is there a way for a live agent to login and chat with a customer using only their mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I'm being down-thumbed on this question, but after some creative Googling I found an idea that addresses this problem. If there's any workarounds, that would be helpful. Thanks.

"Make Omni-Channel available for Salesforce1/Future Lightning Mobile app"

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcInUAJ/make-omnichannel-available-for-salesforce1future-lightning-mobile-app?_ga=2.124343881.233160490.1690139702-564487235.1676278995